# Automatically fill out textbox doble clicking on an item in a listbox

Tags: textbox, listbox, ms-access-2010

Another beginners question, but this time about MS Access Controls.
I have a form where I have a list box full with many items.
What I need to do is when I double click on one of this item stored in the list box should all the textbox filled with an item stored on a different field from the same row where from my table.

I checked many tutorials already but didn't found a good solution.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I have a table with several fields. The list box have the items from the first field(ID). The rest of the fields(Tile, Delivery Date, etc...) represented by text boxes in my form.

When I double Click on one item from the list box will populate the text boxes.
 If I select the 5th item from my list box which represents the 5th row from my table every text box should have their item from the same row from the fields represented in the table.

I only want to edit the data stored in the table with this form.

Comment: *should all the textbox filled with an item stored on a different field from the same row where from my table* -- This is hard to understand, can you edit your question to be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally get a solution for this one.

I using the DLOOKUP to get the data pulled to my form after the double-click event.

```
 Dim ctrloop

 For Each ctrloop In Me.lbReportID.ItemsSelected
      strReportID = Me.lbReportID.ItemData(ctrloop)
 Next ctrloop

 Me.txtTitle = DLookup("[Title]", "tblreports", "[ID No] = '" & strReportID & "'")
```

The loop stores all report ID I have in my table. The `DLOOKUP` using this as a filter. It's like the `WHERE` in SQL.

When the program run will fill out my Title textbox looking through the title field in my `tblreports` table filtered with the `strReportID`.

It's working similarly like this SQL query which I using in a different textbox:

```
SELECT tblReports.[ID No] 
FROM tblReports 
WHERE (((tblReports.WorkPacage) = 'CDS'))  
  AND (((tblReports.State) <> 'Complete'));
```